# System directly booting to Windows without showing GRUB menu

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I have a hp pavillion 15 n203tx with preinstalled Windows 8.1.

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 in it, and then it used to show a GRUB menu every time I turned on the machine. The menu said something like:

```
1. Ubuntu 
2. Advanced options for Ubuntu 
3. Windows Boot Manager(on /dev/sda2) 
4. System Setup
```

Everything was working well. If I wanted to run Ubuntu I chose the Ubuntu option and if I wanted to boot Windows then I chose the third option of Windows Boot Manager.

Out of curiosity once I tried that last option-system setup, and a new menu loaded up, a startup menu showing the following options-

```
1. f1 system information 
2. f2 system diagnostics 
3. f9 boot device options 
4. f10 bios setup 
5. f11 system recovery

enter- continue setup
```

then I pressed <kbd>enter</kbd> and Windows started booting. Since then, my system is booting directly to Windows without showing the GRUB menu.

If I want to see that grub menu, I have to press the <kbd>esc</kbd> key on starting my system. Then the startup menu appears (which I have mentioned above) and I have to press <kbd>f9</kbd>. Then I am presented with a boot menu options screen with the following options:

```
1. OS boot manager
2. Ubuntu
3. Boot from EFI file
```

I have to select the second option to get to the GRUB menu.

I want my system to work as it did earlier.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, but it sounds like F9 would be the right choice. I'm not sure though because every PC I've ever owned uses F12 to select a boot device. If F9 doesn't work try F12. Basically you want to get to the menu where you'd select a boot device (like when you're booting from a live usb) and choose the correct partition.

All you have to do is arrow down to the partition ((device) with Ubuntu installed and press enter. Then open a terminal and type `sudo update-grub`. It should find Ubuntu and re-add it to the grub menu.

Comment: will it make things normal again. I mean on startup it will show grub menu?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to press and hold the Shift button during the boot of the system.
This should allow the grub menu to show up. Then you only need access Ubuntu and set the grub options via "boot repair" or similar programs.
I hope this helps!